# Webpack2 compiles sass/scss into js instead of css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I have written a webpack script which should compile all .scss files into a single css file. The reason why I chose webpack instead of gulp/grunt is because I thought it would be easier to just have a single config file in which all the compilation is done.

The problem I am facing is that scss files are getting compiled to javascript code. Is this something that webpack does by default ?

How do I make it to css ?

code:

```
module.exports = {
     entry: glob.sync('./src/components/**/*.scss') ,
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'css'),
         filename: 'styles.css'
     },
     module: {
       loaders: [
           {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']

          }
        ]
    }
 };
```

Comment: You need to use the Extract Text Webpack Plugin: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin. By default Webpack injects your css into the file, but using this will generate a css file like you want; you will also need to require your master sass file in your entry js file for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/extract-text-webpack-plugin). After installing plugin you need to add some line to your config

At top

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
```

Rewrite loader

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader")
    }
```

Add plugins field to export

```
module.exports = {
    .....
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: 'styles.css'})
    ]
    ...
}
```